# Whats the benefit of using traverse to parent in union find?

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree

I found most union find problem try to traverse through the parent for the `find` method

But traversing seems unnecessary at times when using a set can achieve the same purpose

For example take this question that ask to find the minimum spanning tree

```
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.parent = [i for i in range(n)]
        self.rank = [1 for _ in range(n)]
    
    # make a and b part of the same component
    # union by rank optimization
    def union(self, a, b):
        pa = self.find(a)
        pb = self.find(b)
        if pa == pb: return
        if self.rank[pa] > self.rank[pb]:
            self.parent[pb] = pa
            self.rank[pa] += self.rank[pb]
        else:
            self.parent[pa] = pb
            self.rank[pb] += self.rank[pa]
    
    # find the representative of the 
    # path compression optimization
    def find(self, a):
        if self.parent[a] == a:
            return a
        
        self.parent[a] = self.find(self.parent[a])
        return self.parent[a]
    

class Solution:
    def minCostConnectPoints(self, points: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        
        n = len(points)
        edges = []
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i+1, n):
                dist = abs(points[i][0] - points[j][0]) + abs(points[i][1] - points[j][1])
                edges.append((dist, i, j))
        
        # sort based on cost (i.e. distance)
        edges.sort()
        
        # using Kruskal's algorithm to find the cost of Minimum Spanning Tree
        res = 0
        ds = DisjointSet(n)
        for cost, u, v in edges:
            if ds.find(u) != ds.find(v):
                ds.union(u, v)
                res += cost
        
        return res
```

But here is another union find using set

```
        """
        :type points: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """
        n = len(points)
        edges = []
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i+1, n):
                dist = abs(points[i][0] - points[j][0]) + abs(points[i][1] - points[j][1])
                edges.append((dist, i, j))
        
        # sort based on cost (i.e. distance)
        edges.sort()


        node_to_group = {}
        group = 0
        group_to_node = {}
        cost = 0

        for k in edges:
            nodeA = k[1]
            nodeB = k[2]

            if nodeA in node_to_group and nodeB in node_to_group:
                if node_to_group[nodeA] != node_to_group[nodeB]:
                    
                    groupA = node_to_group[nodeA]
                    groupB = node_to_group[nodeB]

                    final_group = groupB
                    cancel_group = groupA
                    if groupA > groupB:
                        final_group = groupA
                        cancel_group = groupB

                    all_node = group_to_node[cancel_group].keys()

                    del group_to_node[cancel_group]

                    for node in all_node:
                        group_to_node[final_group][node] = True
                        node_to_group[node] = final_group
                    cost += k[0]
                else:
                    pass
            elif nodeA in node_to_group:
                cur_group = node_to_group[nodeA]
                node_to_group[nodeB] = cur_group
                group_to_node[cur_group][nodeB] = True
                cost += k[0]

            elif nodeB in node_to_group:
                cur_group = node_to_group[nodeB]
                node_to_group[nodeA] = cur_group
                group_to_node[cur_group][nodeA] = True
                cost += k[0]

            else:
                node_to_group[nodeA] = group
                node_to_group[nodeB] = group

                group_to_node[group] = {}
                group_to_node[group][nodeA] = True
                group_to_node[group][nodeB] = True
                group += 1
                cost += k[0]

        return cost
```

Why is traversing to the parent preferred in most of the union find implementation

Comment: Can you compress your example to just a few lines of pseudocode?

Comment: Union find data structures use the fastest known implementation. Which implementation is fastest in practice depends on many things, and can only really be determined by an experiment. I don't know what set-based implementation you have in mind, but don't forget that operations on set don't come for free. The set data structure is hiding a lot of complexity under its simple API.